# Deleting and pushing back elements of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to solve a problem that is similar to this one : [Throwing cards away](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=onlinejudge&page=show_problem&problem=1876). The only change in my problem is that I don't need the sequence of discarded cards. I only want the last remaining card.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int n, i;
    while ((scanf ("%d", &n) == 1) && n != 0)
    {
        vector<int> cards;
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            cards.push_back(i);
        }
        while (cards.size() != 1)
        {
            cards.erase(cards.begin());
            cards.push_back(cards.front());
        }
        printf ("%d\n", cards.at(1));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the first time I am using `vector` and all the related STL functions. I checked [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/) and it says that the `erase` function deletes a vector element. So the `while` loop should should keep decreasing the  size of the `vector` till it becomes `1`. But I am not getting an output on running this. I think it's because of an infinite loop, so I tried printing the size of the `vector` in each iteration and saw that the size is reduced only once. So this is causing the infinite loop. However I don't understand why it's not being reduced further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of your vector never drops to 1 because you do not move the front card, but copy it to the end of vector. `cards.push_back(cards.front())` increases the size by one. If your aim is to move the front card to the back of vector then exchange the two lines:

```
    while (cards.size() != 1)
    {
        cards.push_back(cards.front());
        cards.erase(cards.begin());
    }
```

This would not decrease the size of course.

EDIT: Here's the proposed solution which removes the front card and *moves* the next card to the bottom of the deck (vector).

```
    while (cards.size() != 1)
    {
        cards.erase(cards.begin());
        cards.push_back(cards.front());
        cards.erase(cards.begin());
    }
```

The size will effectively decrease by 1 in each iteration.

Comment: Isn't the first element removed and the second copied to the end?

Comment: Yes, the keyword is *copied*, not moved. So the first is removed which decreases the vector size by 1, but the copying again increases the size by one.

Comment: @IgorPopov Is there any STL function that can move the element instead of copying it?

Comment: @reb94 Not sure, I just updated my answer which suggests how to move the fist element to the end of vector simply by exchanging the two lines of his code in the while loop.

Comment: @IgorPopov The first line of the loop copies the first element to the last and then the second line deletes it from the first position. But I want it to be completely removed from the vector. Because even your loop is increasing and then decreasing the size. So the net effect is zero. It again enters an infinite loop.

Comment: @reb94 I updated again the answer. The code removes the front card and *moves* the new top card to the bottom of the deck, as it is demanded at the link you gave in the initial post.

Comment: @reb94 Your program crashes at the printf line. It should read `printf ("%d\n", cards.at(0));` because the indexing starts from zero ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
    while (cards.size() != 1)
    {
        cards.erase(cards.begin()); // cards.size() goes down
        cards.push_back(cards.front()); // cards.size() goes up
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to keep the last element in the vector then you can write

```
if ( !cards.empty() ) cards.erase( cards.begin(), std::prev( cards.end() ) );
```